# How do I run through a list with an IO operation

Tags: haskell, types, io, list-comprehension, monads

So I'm writing a program that checks for every line of a .txt file whether it is a palindrome or not,

```
import System.IO

main :: IO()
main = do {
content <- readFile "palindrom.txt";
print content;
print (lines content);
singleWord (head (lines content));
return ();
}

palindrom :: [Char] -> Bool
palindrom a = a == reverse a

singleWord :: [Char] -> IO()
singleWord a = do { 
print (length a);
print (show (palindrom a));
}
```

But instead of `singleWord (head (lines content))` I need to run the `singleWord` through the entire list.

The problem is that with `map` or normal list comprehension I always get a ton of varying errors all to do with `lines content` (which should be an array of Strings or IO Strings) apparently always being the type I don't want (I've tried messing around with type declarations on that forever, but it keeps being the wrong type, or the right one but in an extra array-layer or whatever).

My last attempt is to walk through the array with recursion, with this little extra code:

```
walkthrough [] = []
walkthrough x = do { singleWord head x; walkthrough (tail x) }
```

which I can't typecast correctly no matter what.

It's supposed to replace the `singleWord (head (lines content))` in `main`, and if I try anything with typeclassing, like

```
walkthrough :: [[Char]] -> [[Char]]
walkthrough [] = ["Hi"]
walkthrough x = do { singleWord head x; walkthrough (tail x) }
```

I get

```
Couldn't match type `IO' with `[]'
      Expected type: [()]
        Actual type: IO ()
```

or some other stuff that won't fit together.

Comment: Is that your actual indentation? After you've solved that problem, I suggest you to head over to [CodeReview.SE].

Comment: @Zeta no its not but ghci keeps complaining about Tabs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for a function called `mapM_`.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do {
  content <- readFile "palindrom.txt";
  mapM_ singleWord (lines content);
};


palindrome :: [Char] -> Bool
palindrome a = (a == reverse a)

singleWord :: [Char] -> IO()
singleWord a = do {
  let {
    adverb = (if palindrome a then " " else " not ");
  };
  putStrLn  (a ++ " is" ++ adverb ++ "a palindrome.");
};
```

Answer (score 3):

That should've been

```
walkthrough [] = return ()                    -- this is the final action
walkthrough x  = do { singleWord (head x)     -- here you missed the parens 
                    ; walkthrough (tail x) }
```

or better yet,

```
walkthrough []     = return () 
walkthrough (x:xs) = do { singleWord x        -- can't make that mistake now!
                        ; walkthrough xs}
```

and call it as `walkthrough (lines content)` in your main `do` block.

As others have pointed out, `walkthrough` is the same as `mapM_ singleWord`.

You could also write it with a list comprehension,

```
walkthrough xs = sequence_ [ singleWord x | x <- xs]
```

`sequence_ :: Monad m => [m a] -> m ()` turns a list of actions into a sequence of actions discarding their results and producing the `()` in the end: `sequence_ = foldr (>>) (return ())`. And `sequence_ (map f xs)` === `mapM_ f xs`, so it all ties up in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Use `mapM_ singleWord  (lines content)`. For the sake of simplicity, think of `mapM_` as.

```
mapM_ :: (a -> IO ()) -> [a] -> IO ()
```